# Encoder in Wowza Streaming server

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, wowza

i am new to wowza media system.just started development two days ago.i am following this tutorial http://www.wowza.com/forums/content....-based-encoder in this there is a heading Publishing the stream in this we have to use our encoder what is this encoder means wheather its an hardware device or any serversider module .please guideline how to specify Host Address and stream name in encoder

Comment: SO apparently truncated the URL you provided. I just tried searching for it on Wowza's forums but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Encoder is a tool which you can use to convert your stream into a desired format. There are both hardware and software encoders but I believe you are interested in software encoders. (list of encoders and how to use them with Wowza can be found [here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?27) )

For starting you might wanna try using "Flash Media Live Encoder" with a webcam attached to your PC.

Host address is the address of your stream server, and stream name is the name for the stream you desire :

Server: rtmp://[wowza-ip-address]/[application-name]

Stream: stream-name

A detailed tutorial can be found [here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36) on Wowza webpage.